# How to do a string replacement with formatting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React application, I'm using string.replace to replace parts of a string with variables, and I'm identifying the variables with `%VARIABLE%` syntax.  And for plain text it works fine:

```js
const text = 'This is %FIRST%, this is %SECOND%, and this is %THIRD%.'
  .replace(/%\w+%/g, ((variable) => ({
    '%THIRD%': 'a pear',
    '%FIRST%': 'an apple',
    '%SECOND%': 'a banana',
  }[variable] || variable)));
console.log(text)
```

But I'm trying to think of a way to format the variable text (e.g. bold formatting), so the text comes out like this:

> This is **an apple**, this is **a banana**, and this is **a pear**.

How can I do this?

Comment: render it as JSX with <strong> tags.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap each replacement in a `span` and apply a specific CSS class and rules. Use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to render the html string into a div/element.

```js
const text = 'This is %FIRST%, this is %SECOND%, and this is %THIRD%.'
  .replace(/%\w+%/g, ((variable) => {
    const value = {
      '%THIRD%': 'a pear',
      '%FIRST%': 'an apple',
      '%SECOND%': 'a banana',
    }[variable] || variable;
    
    return `<span class="bold">${value}</span>`;
  }));
  
console.log(text);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }} />,
  rootElement
);
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Not bad.  But how "dangerously" _is_ `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?  I've avoided it just because of the name.

Comment: @Oystein Only "dangerous" if you don't sanitize what you render, i.e. if you are taking input from a user or external resource. Since you control the string replacement it's likely fine. If you are concerned you can run the string through a sanitizer such as that provided by [dom purify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify) first to strip out any "unsavory" tags/etc before doing the string replacement and injecting your tags.

Comment: I see..  This shouldn't be a problem then, as the HTML tags will come from the frontend code itself.  The string coming from the backend only contains the percenages around the variable name.  Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you dont like `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` you can also use a package called [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser). (I used the CDN version in the snippet below). Basically what it does is converting html code in string format to React elements.

> The parser converts an HTML string to one or more [React elements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser).

```js
const App = () => {
  const text =
    "This is %FIRST%, this is %SECOND%, and this is %THIRD%.".replace(
      /%\w+%/g,
      (variable) =>
        ({
          "%THIRD%": "<b>a pear</b>",
          "%FIRST%": "<b>an apple</b>",
          "%SECOND%": "<b>a banana</b>",
        }[variable] || variable)
    );

  return <p> {window.HTMLReactParser(text)}</p>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/html-react-parser@latest/dist/html-react-parser.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip!  But why use this package over `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?  According to the NPM page it doesn't sanitize the HTML, so you have to do that anyhow..?

Comment: That's true. There clearly are a few negative aspects. Not just sanitizing but also that the library is not XSS safe for instance. Still, it's quite straightforward and definitely good enough for most use-cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage **[React HTML Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)** for this:

```js
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

const Component = () => {
  const text = useMemo(
    () =>
      'This is %FIRST%, this is %SECOND%, and this is %THIRD%.'.replace(
        /%\w+%/g,
        variable => {
          const replacement =
            {
              '%THIRD%': 'a pear',
              '%FIRST%': 'an apple',
              '%SECOND%': 'a banana',
            }[variable] || variable;

          return `<b>${replacement}</b>`;
        },
      ),
    [],
  );

  return <div>{ReactHtmlParser(text)}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with:

```
const var = "an apple"
const text = `This is ${var}`
console.log(text) // output: This is an apple
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The input string is read from a headless CMS, so I can't use template strings.